# MVC and Forms Authentication in separate projects - security risk

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

let's say I have a two projects based on MVC 3. Both of them use the Forms Authentcation mechanism. User is being logged in the 1st project. Then he goes to the 2nd project to log in and what turns out - he is already logged in. How to avoid that scenario ?

Comment: Have you tried using the AntiForgery token used in MVC?

Comment: Make sure auth cookie names differ in both projects

Answer (score 1):

If you do not set the name of the cookie used by the `FormsAuthentication` class then you will encounter that issue when running two asp.net applications at the same time. From the definition of that property:

> The name of the cookie used to store the forms-authentication ticket.
>   The default is ".ASPXAUTH"

So you should notice that there is only one cookie when there should be two (or the number of applications opened).

To resolve the issue you should name the cookie, you can do it in `web.config`

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" name="unique_cookie_name" />
</authentication>
```